# MVC Validation with ViewModel

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have EF4 entities, decorated with DataAnnotations, I have my clientside validation enabled in web.config, and everything. It works, except on some views my @model is a MyViewModel where T is one of the EF4 entities:

```
public class MyViewModel<T>
{
 public T Entity {get;set;}
 public string SomeOtherPropertyWhichDoesntNeedValidation {get;set;}
}
```

Now for some reason validations on T doesn't work when using in a ViewModel. 
Just to clarify, the textboxes are generated by @Html.TextBoxFor(o=>o.Entity.Title); etc.

please help

EDIT: This is how my entity looks like

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TextMeta))]
public partial class Text
{
        class TextMeta
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage="This is required!!!")]
            public string Title { get; set; }
        }
}
```

Comment: What kind of implicit validations can you expect from a string property? Or did you implement manual ones?

Comment: @Vincent Vancalbergh: I've edited the question.

Comment: if you return MyViewModel to view then validation will not occur. and if you have returned "class Text" then i dont see why it will not work. post you Controller and view  here

Comment: I return `MyViewModel<Text>`. How to enable validation on Text's properties (inside the `Entity` property)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TextMeta))] 
public partial class Text {}

public class TextMeta 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="This is required!!!")]
    public string Title { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that is different from my original code... (beside not being a nested class)

Comment: Nesting is one change, explicitly declaring the meta class as public is the 2nd.  Did you try it my way?

Comment: I don't exactly have this project nearby :)